# Efficient way of reusing or disposing custom fonts in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, dispose

We have C# form application, which uses lot of controls and custom font with different sizes in each of them. The problem is with the ever growing FONT gdi object count which causes OutOfMemory Exception(once it crosses 10,000 count - tested this with Bear GDI usage) whenever the controls are recreated. I had tried below options, but the font gdi does not stay consistent:

1. Reuse each font of specific font type/size by declaring it as static variable in a static class

   static Font Robo_13Reg_Font= new Font("Roboto", 13F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ((byte)(0)));
2. Create a local font variable and dispose once it's use is done
3. Reuse font from a label to the required control and dispose the label, as in below code

---

```
 public static void getRobo_13Reg_Font(Control addFontTo)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Robo_13Reg_Font == null)
            {
                Robo_13Reg_Font = new Label();
                Robo_13Reg_Font.Font = new Font("Roboto", 13F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ((byte)(0)));
            }
            addFontTo.Font = Robo_13Reg_Font.Font;
            Robo_13Reg_Font.Dispose();
            Robo_13Reg_Font = null;
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
```

Appreciate all your inputs!

Comment: Instead of creating a new `Font` instance for every control, can you cache the fonts in something like a dictionary keyed by the size of the font?  That way you will only ever have one instance for each size.

Comment: can you please explain how this will solve this issue ,as i have tried similar approach using static variable to hold the font object.

Comment: As @BradleyUffner spotted, OOM probably occurs because you are creating same Font again and again without disposing previous one. Options 1 seems ok, I am not sure what *"font gdi does not stay consistent"* means.

Comment: Well, _CERTAINLY_ don't add the font to the control and dispose of it.  Then the control will have a disposed objects, and bad things can happen.

Comment: I'm actually a little surprised your current code even works.  It calls `Dispose` on a `Font` instance that is actively assigned to a control.  I'm not really sure why you create the intermediate `Label` either, you should be able to work directly with the `Font`.

Comment: If i use option1(i.e., use static font variable), then also i see the font gdi count increasing. although i am disposing and recreating new controls with the previously created static fonts.

Comment: `public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static Font Robo_13Reg_Font = new Font("Roboto", 13F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ((byte)(0)));
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Label ctrl1 = new Label();
            ctrl1.Font = Robo_13Reg_Font;
            Label ctrl2 = new Label();
            ctrl2.Font = Robo_13Reg_Font;
            }
    }`     When i run the above code and inspect, the font gdi count shows as 3 always irrespective of i declare as static/local scope.How do we avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you are creating numerous ToolTip instances(new ToolTip) and assigning font for the tooltip in your app - This also would create font GDI objects for each tooltip instance being created, as i had similiar problem with it.

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem. It was because of the tooltip instances which i was creating along with the controls.